# flutter, sqlite data deletion

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

Encountered a problem when deleting data from a table.Return null when referring to id. I sat there and didn’t understand what the problem was.

```
        Future<void> deleteBook(int? id) async {
          final db = await database;

          print('SQL Query: DELETE FROM books WHERE id = $id');
          // Here it returns zero, although it should return a number
          await db.delete(
            'books',
            where: 'id = ?',
            whereArgs: [id],
          );
        } 


         /\* I thought there was still an opportunity to change it, although in my table 'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY                      AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL' \*/
```

```
      class Book {
        final int? id;
        final String title;
        final String description;
        final String author;

        const Book({
          this.id,
          required this.title,
          required this.description,
          required this.author,
        });  
    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'description': description,
      'author': author,
    };
  }
```

Comment: "Please check whether the 'id' is null, or you may need to debug to determine if the 'id' is null or if the data with the desired 'id' does not exist in the first place."

Comment: Yes, I have a debug, where id data is added in ascending order. I have test data and its display.